# How do I make a rainbow hue shift over time on text?

Tags: unity, c#, color

What I'm trying to do is make a Text object have an animation that allows for the hue of the color to go all the way up and loop back around, so it creates a cool rainbow thing.

I've looked on google for a solution but the solution I found only worked in older versions of Unity, which were used back in 2015.  [What I found](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-rainbow-hue-shift-over-time-c-script.351751/)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [TextMeshPro](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.textmeshpro.html) (which I would recommend for many more reasons - it is just superior to the old Text and TextMesh components), then you can assign a Material to the text. That material can have a shader which allows you to create any kinds of visual effects.

But even when shader programming is not your area of expertise: [The standard shader](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/shaders/) might already be able to do what you want. You can assign a tiling rainbow as a texture and then use the UV Speed property to make it scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Rich Text](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/):

```
string message = "<color="red">R<color="orange">a<color="yellow">i<color="green">n<color="blue">b<color="purple">o<color="red">w";
```

You can use hex code colors for finer control:

```
string message = "<color=#FF000088>Semitransparent red";
```